# Is there a way to extract individual comma separated values from a cell and populate elsewhere in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell on one sheet of a workbook. Values can be separated by lines, or commas, whichever would make this easier.

On another sheet, I would like to display these values in different cells, individually.

Basically I would like to take this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fadBL.jpg

And have it populate this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjgck.jpg

While the code would be nice, I would be happy with the steps I need to take.

I can fairly easily grab the first value out of the cell using:

```
=LEFT(VLOOKUP(O1,Business!A:N,3),(FIND(",",VLOOKUP(O1,Business!A:N,3),1)-1))
```

The second is a little more tedious, I've used:

```
=MID(Q15,FIND(",",Q15)+1,FIND(",",Q15,FIND(",",Q15)+1)-FIND(",",Q15)-1)
```

Do I have to keep doing the same thing for length -1 essentially? Is there someway to simplify this or make it more dynamic?

Please excuse the sample formula cell references, I know they don't match up with the images provided. Hopefully what I'm asking makes enough sense though.

And I also just found this and it works to extract the value between the second and third comma, but I'm not really sure *why* it works.

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(P16,",",REPT(" ",100)),200,100))
```

Comment: There are quite a few unknowns here as of yet. Are you needing to do this for only *one* cell? One cell at a time? All cells all the time? Under what conditions (e.g. one date's cell at a time to be output in the same location? A range of cells corresponding with a span of dates; and if the latter, presented how? The most efficient way to "explain" is to share a link to a sample spreadsheet that is set up exactly like your real spreadsheet, contains a scope of realistic data, and hand-entered results to illustrate where and upon what conditions a formula should return such results.

Comment: In addition, you have tagged both `excel` and `google-sheets`. These are entirely different spreadsheet platforms with wide differences in functionality, available function sets, etc. Please choose one or the other, or clearly indicate that you do not care which solution might be offered (they will not be the same).

Comment: @brad agree with Eric. The fact that you say "I know they don't match up with the images provided" translates to me as, "I'm not going to spend too much time making my question clear to people I want to help me..." I like the Marvel references for examples, but simplify and make it absolutely clear what you want, what's worked, and what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using *Find*, *Mid*, etc. use `=transpose(split(your Cell,","))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try in D151:

```
=INDEX(IFEROR(TRIM(SPLIT(B151:B, ",")&" "&SPLIT(C151:C, ","))))
```